# Rails application throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I followed this guide(http://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails) to try out some basic ajax in my rails application and suddenly I ran into this error, when doing a ´rails s´ command.

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant A
jaxExample (NameError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:4
0:in `block in load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:4
0:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:4
0:in `load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:1
6:in `reload!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:2
6:in `block in updater'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_chec
ke
r.rb:75:in `execute'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb
:2
7:in `updater'
        from c:131071:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in 
`b
lock in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instan
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_c
r.rb:75:in `call'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_c
r.rb:75:in `execute'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader
7:in `updater'
        from c:131071:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:
lock in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `ins
_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `blo
 run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_c
ent'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run
ializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `init
e!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:
ethod_missing'
        from C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Kaspar/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/ajax/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_strin
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_
ns_from_config'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `a
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `s

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in
 (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (re
d)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What is this caused by ?  I did everything as it sayd there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the first line in your routes.rb, it should be:

`<Your app's name>::Application.routes.draw do`

In your case it seems to be:

```
Ajax::Application.routes.draw do
```

Comment: Right, named the application it self differently and went stupid with copying. Thank you for the answer!